# How to transfer model data to another network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement this architecture "Auto-Encoder Guided GAN", what I can not understand is the "supervising clue".
[The architecture that I'm trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvlcf.png)

My questions are:

What is the "supervising clue"?
What is the best way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the original paper? is there an implementation coming with it?

Comment: Paper: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08789) no implemetation available

Comment: I see. The paper seems a bit limited (just 6 pages, no annexes to detail the architecture), I encourage you to contact the authors. You may also profit and ask whether they would share an implementation.